# Is there any benefit to tokenizing and then building an AST?

Tags: parsing, compilation, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there any benefit of tokenizing a source file first and then pushing each token into an AST in separate pass?

The language I'm parsing is *not* context-free; certain tokens will have different meanings in different contexts.

Thus if I do a context-free tokenization then my token names will not make much sense -- I would have tokens like `COMMENT_START_OR_IDENTIFIER_START`.

I could also do a context-aware tokenization and then convert each symbol into the correct token -- `COMMENT_START` and `IDENTIFIER_START` as separate tokens despite both of them being made up of the same string.

But at that point I'm wondering if it's not better to just build the AST in one pass rather than making a linear stream of tokens first, and then parsing *that* into an AST?

Answer (score 3):

A tokenizer should not care what the grammatical purpose of a token is. It merely needs to recognize the token (and possibly associate it with a semantic value, although it should be entirely sufficient to associate it with the source character string.) So as long as it is clear what the boundaries of a token are -- that is, which source characters constitute the token -- it doesn't make the slightest different what the "name" of the token is.

The mere fact that the same character sequence has different semantics in two different grammatical contexts is not sufficient to make a grammar context-sensitive. Here's a dumb example: the grammar describes a list of expressions where each expression can optionally be identified with a number, like this:

```
27: a * b
```

and the value of a number expression can be used:

```
28: $27 + 4
```

Here an integer might be an expression identifier or a constant. But the tokenizer doesn't need to care; it just returns an INTEGER.

```
program: %empty
       | program line
       ;

line   : INTEGER ':' expr
       | expr
       ;

expr   : term
       | expr '*' expr
       | expr '+' expr
         /* ... */
       ;

term   :  IDENTIFIER
       |  INTEGER      { /* a constant */ }
       |  '$' INTEGER  { /* an expression identifier */ }
       ;
```

Even if tokenisation is dependent on grammatical context, the grammar can still be context-free, but it may not be so easy to write a separate lexer. For example, there are a number of languages in which regular expressions can be used directly as constants, surrounded by <kbd>/</kbd>, even though <kbd>/</kbd> is also an arithmetic operator. Javascript and Awk are just two examples. [Note 1]

Actually writing a CFG for such languages is a bit tricky, but it is certainly possible. Scannerless parsers have become popular precisely because of such issues, and a scannerless grammar will demonstrate that the language is still context-free. (It may not be LR(1) anymore, though.)

Traditional yacc/lex parsers can also be used, but since the tokeniser and the parser are independently generated by different tools, it is not so easy to share parser/scanner state between the two. In typical implementations, the scanner for such a language will maintain just enough state to make the decision about what the `/` means, *not* in order to let the parser know but rather in order to be able to switch tokenisation rules for the duration of the regular expression. The resulting parser may not look context-free, but the language parsed still is.

C++ is a true example of a context-sensitive language, since in C++ it is not possible to decide whether <kbd><</kbd> following an identifier is a template bracket or a less-than sign without knowing whether the preceding identifier was a template identifier or not, something which is only possible by looking the identifier up in a symbol table. (Or worse. It's possible to arrange for the decision to require an arbitrarily complicated computation.)

---

## Notes

1. Perl is another example, but Perl doesn't pretend to be context-free.

Comment: (1) The name matters to the clarity of the AST and what I decide to do with the token. A `COMMENT` needs to be handled very differently than an `IDENTIFIER`. If I make them the same token it means I need to add more logic to process the tokens. You're saying it's *better* to put less logic in the tokenizer and more in the token-processor? (2) Good points about 'being context-free'. I'm writing my parser by hand; I guess I've only defined what you'd call the "terminals" so far. I was writing them with "semantics"; e.g., the `*` isn't `ASTERISK` it's `MULTIPLY` but I guess that's the wrong...

Comment: ...approach. Terminals should be "dumb", then I don't need to define different tokens for them. But the non-terminals, those *kind of* depend on context, don't they? For example, you can only have an `expr` after the `INTEGER:` bit. Their position matters. So what does "context" mean then? Does it specifically mean you need to look-ahead, or that you need to refer to a symbol table? I don't think I'll need that for my language, just 'look-behinds'.

Comment: @Mark: The AST should (imho) be based on non-terminals. The traditional division into terminals (lexical units) and non-terminals (syntactic units) indeed means that terminals are "dumb", as you say -- in my example, there is no real semantic information associated with an INTEGER, since its meaning is dependent on which non-terminal produces it. Roughly speaking, a terminal is like a C type: the fact that `a_variable` is an `int` is useful to know, but it gives you no information about what `a_variable` actually represents -- it could a count (of something), a size (of something), an index...

Comment: @Mark:  For your second question, `context-free` is a very specific concept in parsing theory, and I'd refer you to a good book on the subject, or failing that the wikipedia page, because the answer is too long even for a pair of comments and certainly out-of-scope for SO.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Many parsing libraries and code generators use the tokenization phase to improve performance. This is because because it easy to implement tokenization using a simple state machine without backtracking. A naive recursive descent parser that incorporates tokenization can perform a significant amount of reparsing of the same input if it tries and fails to match different production rules.

That said, many PEG parsing libraries nonetheless blend both tokenization and parsing phases and use techniques like memoization to speed up parsing.

In my own parsing library (https://github.com/cdiggins/myna-parser) I combine both phases and do not use memoization. Instead I rely on careful construction of the grammar to minimize back-tracking.